# 404 error on push notification using sample code

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I got my url from the app. It begins with:

```
http://sn1.notify.live.net/throttledthirdparty/01.00/
```

and if I navigate to that URL using a browser, I get the message:

```
Microsoft Push Notification Server
```

I then grabbed the code provided by Microsoft.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402545%28v=VS.92%29.aspx
```

If I take the C# code, and use it as is (changing only the URL, the Payload to be an empty byte array, and changing the "" string to Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

I get a 404 every time.

Because I don't get a 404 from by browser, the content must matter, and the push notification servers are dependent on content, so if I change it to a simple raw notification by removing the notification message and adding (as they recommend):

```
        byte[] notificationMessage = new byte[] {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};
        sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "13");
```

I still get a 404 every time. I've tried doing toast notifications with the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting mine to work after binding toast notifications to the shell. I had a method which did it, but under some cases wasn't calling that method.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting a 404 is because the notificationMessage data you are sending isn't what it's expecting. Try this out and see if it works.

You can find a tutorial here:
http://benjii.me/2011/04/push-notifications-in-windows-phone-7-3-push-that-notification/

```
string template =
        "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" +
        "<wp:notification xmlns:wp='WPNotification'>" +
            "<wp:toast>" +
                "<wp:text1>{0}</wp:text1>" +
                "<wp:text2>{1}</wp:text2>" +
            "</wp:toast>" +
        "</wp:notification>";

string toastXML = string.Format(template, "Testing", "This is a test");

byte[] notificationMessage = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(toastXML);
```

Comment: Where did you find this template? You use single quotes instead of double quotes and the tags are not capitalized, which is different than what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) documentation say.

Comment: I got it to work sending by the XML as specified in the MSDN documentation. Perhaps both versions (lower case and capitalized) work. 404 is not caused directly by a bad XML. If you send a bad XML, you'll get a response that suggests success (200/Connected/Active/Received). Only later, when you send another notification to the same channel (with either valid or invalid XML), you may get 404. The 404 is caused by the channel not being valid anymore. The reason for the channel not being valid anymore is the previously sent invalid XML.